# How to stop JavaScript from generating an HTML file with nothing but a JS function call in it

Tags: javascript, function

When using an EventListener in a javascript file to call a function
`document.getElementById("messageSubmit").addEventListener("click", getKey)`
however, when running my code, JS throws a ReferenceError saying that getKey() is not defined (it is) and, to show me where the error occurred, points me to `index.html`, which now only contains one line: `getKey()`. When looking at the files in Inspect Element, my original `index.html` is there, and fully intact. What on earth is happening, and how do I go about fixing it?

I have tried changing `getKey` to `getKey()` in the EventListener, and I have tried deleting the new file, however my IDE does not recognise that the new file exists, or has ever existed. (my IDE is WebStorm by JetBrains)
I won't post the entire JS file, as it's ~50000 lines, but here's the problematic function and call.

```
async function startChat(user, userkey, userPubKey, oUID, position) { //Will start an encrypted chat between two users FIXME: Needs rewriting
    targetUID = oUID;
    var localUID = user.uid;
    console.log(position);
    var order = position === "true" ? localUID + " " + targetUID : targetUID + " " + localUID;
    console.log(order);
    var accepted;
    await database.ref("/chats/" + order + "/accepted/" + targetUID + "/").once('value', function(snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.val() != null) {
            accepted = snapshot.val();
        }
    });
    if (accepted === "true") {
        database.ref("/chats/" + order + "/" + localuuid + "/messages/").on("child_added", (data, prevChildKey) => {
            var newpost = data.val();
            console.log(newpost);
            Object.keys(newpost).sort();
            console.log(newpost);
            const ordered = Object.keys(newpost).sort();
            // Object.keys(newpost).map((key, index) => {
            //
            //
            // }).catch( (error) => {
            //     console.log(error.message);
            //     console.log(error.code);
            // });
            console.log(newpost['message']); //{Prints encrypted message(all messages looped)
            console.log(newpost['date']);//Prints date stamp(all messages looped)
            console.log(newpost['time']);//Prints time stamp(all messages looped)
            console.log(newpost['sender']);//Prints sender uid(all messages looped)
            //var decrypt = cryptico.decrypt(newpost['message'], userkey).plaintext;

            // noinspection JSJQueryEfficiency
            $("#chatField").append("<span>" + newpost['sender'] + "</span>");
            // noinspection JSJQueryEfficiency
            $("#chatField").append("<span>" + newpost['time'] + "</span>");
            // noinspection JSJQueryEfficiency
            $("#chatField").append("<span>" + newpost['message'] + "</span>");
        }).catch( (error) => {
            console.log(error.message);
            console.log(error.code);
        });
    } else {
        var myRef = firebase.database().ref("/chats/" + order + "/accepted/" + oUID).set("false");
    }

document.getElementById("listHere").addEventListener("click", startChat);
```

error:

```
index.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: getKey is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (index.html:1)
```

On clicking on the linked index.html file, it shows:

```
getKey();
```

and nothing else.

How do I fix this, or, if there is no way, is there a workaround?
EDIT: Someone asked for HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ChatLayoutStyleSheet.css">
    <title>ChatLayout</title>
    <script src="cryptico/cryptico-js-master/lib/cryptico.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="InfoPage.html">Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="chatlayout.html">Chat</a></li>
        <li><a href="ChatLayoutGC.html">Groupchat</a></li>
        <li><a href="signin.html">Sign In</a></li> <!-- DON'T TOUCH THIS -->
        <li><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li> <!-- DON'T TOUCH THIS EITHER -->
    </ul>

    <h1 style = "color: white;" id= "title">Welcome To Your Private Chat Room!</h1>
    <h3 style = "color: white;" id="chatName">Invite your friends to start chatting</h3>
    <div class = center2 id="chatField">Display Text Here</div>

    <div class= center>
        <label for="sendmessage" id="messageLabel">Send Message</label>
        <input id="sendmessage" type="text" name="Type" placeholder="Type Here"><br>
        <button type="submit" value="Send" id="messageSubmit">Send</button>
    </div>
    <div id="newchat">
            <label for="findEmail" class="findChat">Search Emails</label>
            <input id="findEmail" type="email" class="findChat">
            <input id="findEmailSubmit" class="findChat" onclick="//parseSearchedEmails()" type="submit">

        <button id="listHere" onclick=""></button>
        <!-- ENCRYPTION PASSPHRASE INPUT REMOVED. DO NOT ADD THAT BACK. THANK YOU. -->
    </div>
</body>
<footer>
    <script src="bundledCHATJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like you actually have `<a onclick="foo()">`. Where is your HTML?

Comment: Are both getEle... and func..foo() in your code exactly like above in the same file?

Comment: No, the names are different. I should replace those.

Comment: Since the error message indicates an `HTMLAnchorElement` (otherwise known as `<a>`), I don't think you're looking at the right `.html` file

Comment: the HTML you show has typos (`</form` has no closing `>`) and doesn't load any JS at all, so this can't possibly be the HTML involved in what you're describing

Comment: I was using `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getKey">, but after seeing this I switched it to a button. Same error, but with HTMLButtonElement.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Edited with the copied file

Comment: The js you show has no mention whatsoever of the string `getKey`. That's not "*the problematic function and call*".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a scope problem (but it cannot be confirmed and solved with elements provided). Here's a very basic example with a raw closure that exports to global scope (basic of a web app noawadays) to demonstrate :

```js
// Simulate a bundle with some exports
(function(global) {
  function t1() {
    alert('Success : all is done in the closure scope');
  }
  
  function t2() {
    alert('Fails : callback not available in event setter scope');
  }
  
  // Exports to global scope
  global.t3 = function() {
    alert('Success : callback is exported to event setter scope');
  };

  // This will be set up within closure scope. It works
  document.getElementById('test1').addEventListener('click', t1);
})(window)

// This will be set up within window scope and t3 available. It works
document.getElementById('test3').addEventListener('click', t3);

// This will be called within window scope and t2 not available. It fails.
document.getElementById('test2').addEventListener('click', t2);
```

```html
<button id="test1">test 1 (OK)</button>
<button id="test2">test 2 (KO)</button>
<button id="test3">test 3 (OK)</button>
```

t2 do **exist** but is not available in current scope when setting up event callback, therefore the `not defined` error. The only way to solve this is to check code structure.

I'm not used to Webstorm and the kinda fake `index.html` might simply be an artifact from the debugger. The JS code you've provided is useless, it's the wrong HTML element id (`listHere` instead of `messageSubmit`) and there's no `getKey` on sight.

By the way, if you use `addEventListener('click', myFunc())` instead of `addEventListener('click', myFunc)`, it will run the callback when setting up listener and not when the event occurs.